# Magento Water Mark ONLY in Zoom Images

Tags: magento, watermark

I want my watermark ONLY in zoom images.
I don't want the water mark in the Thumbnail images.

Someone can help me ?

Magento 1.7

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php place your image destinations `watermark and zoom image paths`

Comment: Hello Kashif,

Sorry I'm just a beginner.
Could you explain better how I should proceed.

I need to create a new file?
I need to change any existing file?
Where should I put this file?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: check the solution below

Answer (score 0):

You can use magento default watermarks option no need to code, go to `Configuration >> Design >> Product image watermarks`

here you can assign watermarks to any OR all Product images.

As you said you dont want watermarks on thumbnails but you havn't mentioned the images you are usning for product page, by default `Base image` is used for product page.